# Counting number of lines in a JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, count

I have a .json file which contains a JSON item on every line. I want to try and count how many JSON items I have within the file using Python. I am currently just counting the lines using the following code

```
count =0
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        count+=1
```

This seems like an unefficient way of doing it though. Is there a more efficient way of either calculating the number of JSON items in a .json file or counting the number of lines within a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit to fix my wrong doing:

This is a one liner for counting lines in file.

```
num = sum(1 for line in open(filename))
```

Comment: This assumes that the *JSON items* the OP is using are JSON objects with just one key.. The OP is counting *lines* here instead.

Comment: Why do you think reading and scanning a line would be quicker than just reading a line? The OP specified that each line is a distinct JSON item so there should be no need to check for that.

Comment: How do you know that `":"` isn't a substring of an element?

Comment: Apologies, will delete shortly.